# monkey runner for another application

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Can i use "monkey runner" to test another application?

I want to integrate the monkey runner in my code so that i can provide input data through my application and then run the 3rd party application.

Answer (score 0):

MonkeyRunner gives ability to automate user clicks and actions. If you want to provide input data and run the third party application use InstrumentationTestCase or its subclass.

Refer to this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html